# Array.push is being affected by post Array.unshift call

Tags: javascript

I am pushing an array to a second array then unshifting and popping the first array but for some reason this is affecting the second one. Why is this? I would like resultsList to equal `[0,1,0,0]` but it ends up being `[0,0,1,0]`

```
var pattern = [0,1,0,0];   
var resultsList = [];

resultsList.push( pattern );
pattern.unshift( pattern.pop() );
console.log( resultsList );
```

Here is a JSFiddle to make it easier to comprehend.

http://jsfiddle.net/ce6us1jk/3/

Comment: resultsList is not `[0,1,0,0]`, it is an array of length 1 containing the (mutable) `pattern`. Did you want `var resultsList = pattern.slice()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the array, otherwise it is passed by reference.

To copy the array, use:

```
pattern.slice(0)
```

Comment: Got you because arrays are just pointers in JavaScript. So no matter how much later I change pattern it'll always be updated in resultsList.

Answer (score 1):

`pattern.pop()` removes and returns the last item in `pattern`.

`pattern.unshift(item)` adds `item` at the beginning of `pattern`.

So the output is expected:

```
[   0, 1, 0, 0 ]
  Λ          |
  |__________|
```